# Client Hello data printed out in ASCII

Tags: python, ssl, networking, ascii, handshake

I am trying to extract some Client Hello information from a network packet.
I am actually printing some values just for testing.

```
def parse_client_hello(handshake):
    if isinstance(handshake.data, dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello):
        client = dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello(str(handshake.data))
        print(client.random)
        print(client.version)
```

The result is as the above :

[image]

Is the printed out data represented in ASCII?
Why is the data printed out in ASCII when in fact the captured packet is in binary?
How can I print it in another form , for ex. in hexadecimal?

Thank you!

Comment: By definition the random part is ... random, so why expecting ASCII? As for the version, TLS 1.2 is version `0x303` in fact or 771 in decimal.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek how can I turn the random part into a more readable way?

Comment: It is a list of bytes theoretically (double check what the library gives you, it depends on the Python version too, you are not saying) and then look at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes : `.hex()` could help.

Comment: For TLS version numbers look at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/tls1.h for example.

Answer (score 0):

New in Python version 3.5: [`bytes.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```py
        ...
        print(client.random.hex())
        print(client.version)
```

---

If you're on anything older than that, [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) will work:

```py
from binascii import hexlify
...

        ...
        print(hexlify(client.random))
        print(client.version)
```

---

Or a bilingual solution:

```py
if hasattr(bytes, 'hex'):
    b2h = bytes.hex
else:
    from binascii import hexlify as b2h
...

        ...
        print(b2h(client.random))
        print(client.version)
```